# Grid System- Is it possible?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My code is bellow:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">Some Codes Here</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">Some Codes Here</div</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">Some Codes Here</div>
</div>
```

1. I want to use a content which Width is suppose 400px & Height: 300px at 1st row/1st column
2. I want to use a content which Width is 400px & Height: **600px** at 1st row/2nd column
3. I want to use a content which Width is 400px & Height: 300px at 2nd row.

I want that 2nd content, which width: 400px & Height: 600px will display upto 2nd Row

[image: I need codes for this Grid]

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a grid system that you're __not__ fixing widths to pixel values?

Comment: Bootstrap was created for responsive design to work on devices with different screen sizes.  You can maintain your desired proportions but not the exact dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can do with bootstrap:

http://www.codeply.com/go/KaIvNu7qCT

Look at snippet:

```css
.wrp1 {
    background: orange;
    height: 25vw;
}
.wrp2 {
    background: teal;
    height: 25vw;
}
.wrp3 {
    background: tomato;
    height: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 wrp1">content1</div>    
                <div class="col-xs-12 wrp2">content2</div>    
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 wrp3">content3</div>    
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```